# Xml default attribute values ignored by parsers

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xsd, attr

I'm trying to parse XMl file with `SAX`, `Stax` and `DOM` parsers (according to my assignment). The problem I'm experiencing is that all of the parsers seem to ignore default values of attributes  specified in the XSD Schema.

```
 <complexType name="Tariff" abstract="true">
    <sequence>
        <element name="id" type="ID" />            
        <element name="monthly-fee" type="float" />
    </sequence>
    <attribute name="status" type="trns:Status" use="optional" default="active"/>
</complexType>

<complexType name="LocalTariff">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="trns:Tariff">
            <sequence>
                <element name="internal-charge" type="trns:CallCharge" />
                <element name="external-charge" type="trns:CallCharge" />
            </sequence>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

Here's attribute type definition:

```
<simpleType name="Status">
    <restriction base="string">
        <enumeration value="active"></enumeration>
        <enumeration value="supported"></enumeration>
        <enumeration value="unavailable"></enumeration>
    </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

I've expected parser to automatically insert missing attributes with default values.

```
<local-tariff>
    <id>id1</id>       
    <monthly-fee>20.5</monthly-fee>
    <internal-charge>3.7</internal-charge>
    <external-charge>2.5</external-charge>
</local-tariff>
```

My guess is that I haven't specified some **parameter** to make parser **take my XSD into consideration**.

Could anyone please enlighten me on this subject? I'm new to XML. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for comes from the [Post-Schema Validation Infoset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_(W3C)#Post-Schema-Validation_Infoset) not from a SAX parser.   A parser only tells you what's in the document.  You want what's implied by the schema, which means you must have a step where you actually validate against a schema, otherwise how is the system to know what's implied by the schema?

[Here is a link](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-xs.html#faq-8) on how to use the PSVI as part of a SAX parser provided by Apache Xerces.   Code might look like this:

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();
PSVIProvider psviProvider = (PSVIProvider)reader;
```

Then look at the [javadocs](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xs/index.html?org/apache/xerces/xs/PSVIProvider.html).  You can get information about any attribute, to include what its default value would be under the schema.

Comment: Thanks, your answer has helped me to start thinking in the right direction. As to SAX, I came up with the following solution:

`private XMLReader reader;
...
reader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();  

reader.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema", Boolean.TRUE);`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a schema-aware parser.  XML and XSD are two different specs; any schema-aware processor will necessarily conform to the XML spec, but there are plenty of XML parsers that don't conform to the XSD spec.